# High Order Functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

I am learning about high-order functions in python.
I want to understand how arguments pass from the inner function to the outer function.

**Say we have a function that counts how many times another function has run.**

```
def counter(fn, counters):
    print("Creating Outer Function - counter")
    cnt = 0
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Creating Inner Function")
        nonlocal cnt
        cnt +=1
        counters[fn.__name__] = cnt
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

c = dict() # This is a dictionary that contains functions and count how many times they ran.

def add_num(a, b):
    return a+b

counted_add = counter(add_num, c)

counted_add(10, 20) # THIS PART I DON'T UNDERSTAND!!!
```

**The last line in the above code I don't understand... How did the outer function manage to understand that 10 and 20 are the args of the inner function?**

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the code clearly, the outer function `counter` is returning the inner function `inner`

see `return inner` at the end of `counter(fn, counters)`

> 

```
def counter(fn, counters):
    print("Creating Outer Function - counter")
    cnt = 0
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Creating Inner Function")
        nonlocal cnt
        cnt +=1
        counters[fn.__name__] = cnt
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner ## HERE
```

The returned inner function is being assigned to `counted_add` at

> `counted_add = counter(add_num, c`)

Now `counted_add` is nothing but `inner` function inside the `counter` function

Calling `counted_add(10, 20)` is equivalent to calling `inner(10, 20)`

I highly recommend you to visit [python visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to better understand the flow

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[Great explanation of high order functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/higher-order-functions-in-python/)

The link above explains everything perfectly. I recommend it as I've used it in past to learn how it all works.

```
counted_add = counter(add_num, c)

counted_add(10, 20)
```

The most basic way I could explain that is: you 'named' function counter and you set the name to counted_add. That's why then you can call that function by using counted_add(10, 20). If that makes any sense :D I am not great at explaining.